# Anchor tag not working intermittently in div

Tags: html, css

I have this anchor tag inside div and it appears as popup. **My anchor is clickable but its not navigating to the url in href and this issue occurs intermittently.** Please help me with is as i don't understand what is causing the issue.

```css
 .button {
  display: block;
  width: 360px;
  margin-top: 1em;
  padding: 1em;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0.25em;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 1.75em;
  text-align: left;
  z-index: 10;
}

a.button:hover, .ff-form button:hover,
.ff-form input[type="reset"]:hover,
.ff-form input[type="button"]:hover,
.ff-form input[type="submit"]:hover {
  -webkit-transition: 0.4s;
  -moz-transition: 0.4s;
  -o-transition: 0.4s;
  transition: 0.4s;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer">
      <a class="button" href="http://iffi.shop.com/cart">GO TO BASKET</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you also place the HTML part where the anchor tag can be found?

Comment: <div class="footer">
            <a class="button" href="http://iffi.shop.com/cart">GO TO BASKET</a>
</div>

Comment: Add `http://` to your link or use a relative link.

Comment: with this part of the code works. Maybe depend on other part of code.

Comment: @domdom i have already tried this but its not working

Comment: Since you said it opens in a popup, I assume some JavaScript is involved? If so, maybe the issues lies within the JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

In your href url I removed the "cart". Then it is working. With cart I think it is not a correct url.

```css
 .button {
      display: block;
      width: 360px;
      margin-top: 1em;
      padding: 1em;
      border: none;
      border-radius: 0.25em;
      text-align: center;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      font-size: 1em;
      font-weight: bold;
      display: inline-block;
      margin-right: 1.75em;
      text-align: left;
      z-index: 10;
    }

a.button:hover, .ff-form button:hover,
.ff-form input[type="reset"]:hover,
.ff-form input[type="button"]:hover,
.ff-form input[type="submit"]:hover {
  -webkit-transition: 0.4s;
  -moz-transition: 0.4s;
  -o-transition: 0.4s;
  transition: 0.4s;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer">
            <a class="button" href="http://iffi.shop.com">GO TO BASKET</a>
</div>
```

Comment: The url mentioned in href is a dummy url, but actually this is pointing to my local

Comment: Are you getting the url working when tried from your browser?

Comment: With the actual url it looks fine to me

Comment: if you try to run the code snippet i have given above, you can see that it is working.

Answer (score 0):

Just a few questions

Is your site running on HTTPS? Is there mixed content on the page? This *could* stop the link from working as your href is http://

Have you tried using Chrome Developer Tools to identify any Javascript issues? (Hit F12 when viewing your page in Chrome)

Are there any other dependencies on the page (jQuery/Bootstrap/etc...)? It looks like you've only posted the bit thats not working.

I've started a jsfiddle for you to debug it

https://jsfiddle.net/nt5cez2f/

Maybe you could add a bit more to it so I can get a bit more context as to whats happening. Notice I've changed link to HTTPS and it works but when it's HTTP it doesn't. This may just be a jsfiddle thing, but is it the same problem you are experiencing?

```
<div class="footer">
  <a href="https://iffi.shop.com/cart">GO TO BASKET</a>
</div>
```

Post back any info you find and I'll try and help you out

Comment: Thanks much @Jhon i have changed the url by putting actual https url, but no luck

Comment: Did you get anything useful out of Chrome Developer Tools? I usually find it invaluable in fixing bugs such as this one.